# Find Equivalent Classes

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recreational-mathematics

Define the relation $\mathrel{R}$  on the set of non-negative integers $\mathbb{Z} \geq 0$ by

$x\mathrel{R}y \iff 11 | 3x+8y$

Can someone please help me figure out what are the equivalence classes $x\mathrel{R}$ for $x$ in $\mathbb{Z} \geq 0$?

Note: $a|b$ means $a$ divides $b$.

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange. People are more likely to help you if you show us you made an effort to answer the question.

Comment: **Duplicate** of [**this question**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2925914/is-equivalence-relation-on-z-possible)

Comment: I proved that it was transitive, reflexive and symmetric but I don't know how to find the equivalent classes in order to define the quotient set.

Answer (score 1):

$$11\,|\,3x+8y\ \overset{-11y}\iff\ 11\,|\, 3(x-y)\ \iff\ 11\,|\,x-y$$
meaning that $x$ and $y$ give the same remainder modulo $11$.

Comment: I proved that it was transitive, reflexive and symmetric but I don't know how to find the equivalent classes in order to define the quotient set. –